# The definition of limits in mathematics

Tags: limits

I was always bother with the definition of the limit as in (cf. screenshot)

It seems to me that there is lacking a relationship to decrease the value of $\epsilon$ as $x$ gets closer to $p$. This definition does not seem to capture this, or at least I can't see it, can you explain/develop on this?

(i.e. there should be something saying that as we diminish $\delta$, the value of  $\epsilon$ diminishes (i.e. moves towards 0) also?)

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

After reading your nice answers, thanks, maybe I should say, since we must consider ''for a given $\epsilon$'' and not for a ''given $\delta$'', yet if we ''challenge'' $\delta$ with an extremely low $\epsilon$ then inevitably $\delta$ should be lower i.e. restraining the value of $x$ to be closer to $p$?

Comment: The idea in this definition is not that there is any relationship as you mention, but rather no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, there is a value $\delta$ that causes the specified results.

Comment: "should be something saying that ...": why? The definition as it is works fine.

Comment: There is a competition between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. $\epsilon$ gets to go first and challenges $\delta$ "beat that".

Comment: nice! yes and then if $\epsilon$ challenges with a very small number must $\delta$ not be usually smaller?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of limits runs counter to the intuition by which they are usually explained.

The intuitive explanation:

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = L$

As $x$ gets closer and closer to $a, f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $L.$

But the actual definition begins with a look at the image of $f(x).$  It says, define a neighborhood in the image.  $\epsilon$ determines the size of this neighborhood.

For any neighborhood in the image around $L,$ there is a neighborhood in the domain such that everything in that neighborhood will map inside the target in the image.  And since we said "any neighborhood in the image" we can make it arbitrarily small.

Comment: Could I rephrase it as : the neighborhood of f(x) being [0;epsilon] there exists a neighborhood [0;delta] in the input space. But from this, it does not stem that delta will be smaller, and in fact the reason why i "want it to said" that delta should be smaller, is that we require x to get closer to be and therefore reduce the difference, do you see what I mean?

Comment: Delta doesn't have to be particularly small.  In an extreme case consider a constant function. $f(x) = 1.$  We can choose an arbitrary value for delta, say 1. and for any $\epsilon > 0; |x-a|< 1 \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

Comment: yes but that seems a bit artificial with the constant function, as usually we want to get the x closer and closer to $p$ (or $a$ in your formulation)?

Comment: It is not required, but it is generally true.  Frequently to prove a limit exists we find a delta that is a function of epsilon. e.g.  $\delta = \max (1,\frac {\epsilon}{2})$  Then, for any $\epsilon$ we have shown that an appropriate delta exists, and when $\epsilon$ is small $\delta$ is also small.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case the relationship is there since $\delta$ is now function of $\epsilon$!

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition,
$$\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = L \tag 1$$
if and only if *for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, you can find a $\delta > 0$,* such that etc. etc.

There are three important points:

1. The $\varepsilon$ is *given*, and if $(1)$ holds, a suitable $\delta$ can be *found*, depending on said $\varepsilon$. Not the other way around. (Indeed, some texts like to underline the dependency of $\delta$ from $\varepsilon$ by writing "For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$, such that...")
2. The statement holds **for every $\varepsilon > 0$** you might be given.
3. For each given $\varepsilon$ there may be multiple suitable $\delta$'s.

Point 2. entails, in particular, that you may pick a sequence $\{\varepsilon_n\}$ of strictly positive real numbers such that $\varepsilon_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$, e.g. $\varepsilon_n = 1/n^2$. If $(1)$ holds, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ you will then be able to find a $\delta > 0$ such that etc. etc., and call it e.g. $\delta_n$. So, as you can see, the broad-looking statement "for every positive real $\varepsilon$" *contains* within itself the idea of a shrinking process.

Answer (score 0):

The key is, this needs to hold **for any value of epsilon**. For any epsilon you choose, you can find a (non-unique) delta that makes it work, no matter how small that epsilon might be.

If you want to put an upper bound on delta, you can show that this bound can never increase as epsilon gets smaller—but the chosen epsilon determines (infinitely many possible values for) delta, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

But in fact $\delta$ does *not* have to decrease as $\epsilon$ decreases.

Say $f(t)=1$ and we want to verify that $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=1$. For $\epsilon=1$ we can take $\delta=1$; then for $\epsilon=1/2$ we can use $\delta=10$ if we want.

Comment: Ah I think my mis-interpretation comes from the logical statement "for every epsilon, there exists..." instead of me wanting to say "for any small delta..."

Comment: While this is perfectly true, the *upper bound* on the value of delta has to be non-increasing as epsilon decreases, which I think is what OP means.

Comment: What is maybe troubling me is that your example seems a bit artificial  (compared to the ones where the function is more complex) in the sense that the function is constant

Comment: So in a sense the fact the t -> 0 is already stated in the lim(.) formula and we don't need to emphasize that in the definition with $\delta$?